# jQuery on thumbnail click replace second img src with thumbnail src

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, each, src

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yKTyz/18/)
On pressing a `.miniimg/2/3` it should replace the src of an img classed `.presentimg` which i have appended using jquery to the div `.imgcontainer`, I have been through the jQuery *(BELOW HTML)* and the only reason i think it wont work because of the fact i have used a function within a function and i do not know an alternative method

```
<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="minicontainer">
    <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_Zuzii37VUO4/Ta0nUeMwXoI/AAAAAAAAFoc/7f0Um7OTgNg/s000/Antartic-by-Peter-Rejcek.jpg" title="icy mountains" class="miniimg"/>
    <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_Zuzii37VUO4/Ta0nUFUhg6I/AAAAAAAAFoY/GToUxRYcteY/s000/Antartic-by-Kelly-Speelman.jpg" title="icy planes and hills" class="miniimg2"/>
    <img src="http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/_Zuzii37VUO4/Ta0nTs8AbPI/AAAAAAAAFoU/zCvNKv4kfe4/s000/BeachWaves-By-RePublicDomain.jpg" title="sun rise with clouds" class="miniimg3"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery, in the jquery I use (index) for the outer .each function as i saw it on a forum but i dont not know if that actually works unfortuately

```
$(".imgcontainer").each(function(){
    var imgsrc = $(".minicontainer img:first-child").attr("src");
    $(this).append('<img src="'+imgsrc+'" class="presentimg"/>');
});
$(".miniimg").each(function(index){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(){
        var miniimgrc = $this.attr("src");
        $(".presentimg").atrr('src', miniimgrc);
    });
});
$(".miniimg2").each(function(index){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(){
        var miniimgrc2 = $this.attr("src");
        $(".presentimg").atrr('src', miniimgrc2);
    });
});
$(".miniimg3").each(function(index){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(){
        var miniimgrc3 = $this.attr("src");
        $(".presentimg").atrr('src', miniimgrc3);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think your problem is that you have several misspellings of `attr`:

```
$(".presentimg").atrr('src', miniimgrc3);
```

should be:

```
$(".presentimg").attr('src', miniimgrc3);
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nv9em/

Additionally, you can shorten your code to just one event handler:

```
$(".imgcontainer").each(function() {
    var imgsrc = $(".minicontainer img:first-child").attr("src");
    $(this).append('<img src="' + imgsrc + '" class="presentimg"/>');
});

$(".miniimg, .miniimg2, .miniimg3").click(function() {
    var miniimgrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $(".presentimg").attr('src', miniimgrc);
});
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fr5yW/

Comment: well thats embarrasing :/ sorry.

Comment: @Fiddler: No problem, sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes `:)`. I have a suggestion on how to make it all shorter as well

Comment: thankyou very much but i have another problem i've been trying to use each but it doesn't seem to be working http://jsfiddle.net/nv9em/1/

Comment: @Fiddler: You need to determine the correct `img.presentImg` based on the small `img` that was clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/aFNjV/

Comment: is there any way of avoiding the .presentimg for each .img container from having the same src as the .miniimg on the page

Comment: @Fiddler: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: if you look at the result on jsfiddle the appended imgs with the classes `.presentimg` have the same src value BUT the first `.miniimg` src is different for both of the divs `.minicontainer`

Comment: could you pleace help me with replacing the .currentimgtitle title value with the title of the thumbnail clicked ive updated it quite a lot since before http://jsfiddle.net/Plugins4/T3J3r/14/

Comment: @Fiddler: I'd recommend asking a new question at this point, just to keep questions and answers out of the comments for this answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696306/img-thumbnail-click-replace-div-text-value