# img thumbnail click replace div text value with thumbnail title

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, title, attr

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Plugins4/T3J3r/25/)

If you look at the js fiddle you will find clicking the thumbail changes the image aswell as the `.currentimgtitle` text value but it changes all `.currentimgtitle` text values on the page when i only want to change the one relevant to it the jquery and html are below

```
$(".imgcontainer").each(function() {
    var imgsrc = $(".minicontainer img:first-child", this).attr("src");
    var imgtitle = $(".minicontainer img:first-child", this).attr("title");
    $(this).append('<div class="presentouter"><img src="' + imgsrc + '" class="presentimg"/><div class="currentimgtitle" title="' + imgtitle + '">' + imgtitle + '</div></div>');
});
$(".miniimg, .miniimg2, .miniimg3").click(function() {
    var miniimgrc = $(this).attr("src"),
        $presentImg = $(this).closest(".imgcontainer").find(".presentimg");

    $presentImg.attr('src', miniimgrc);
});
$(".miniimg, .miniimg2, .miniimg3").click(function(index) {
    var miniimgtitle = $(this).attr("title"),
        $presentTitle = $(this).closest(".imgcontainer").find(".currentimgtitle");

    $presentTitle.attr('title', miniimgtitle);

});
$(".imgcontainer").each(function(index) {
$(".miniimg, .miniimg2, .miniimg3").click(function() {
    var textval =  $(this).attr("title");
    $(".currentimgtitle").text(textval);
});
});
<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="minicontainer">
    <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_Zuzii37VUO4/Ta0nUeMwXoI/AAAAAAAAFoc/7f0Um7OTgNg/s000/Antartic-by-Peter-Rejcek.jpg" title="icy mountains" class="miniimg"/>
    <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_Zuzii37VUO4/Ta0nUFUhg6I/AAAAAAAAFoY/GToUxRYcteY/s000/Antartic-by-Kelly-Speelman.jpg" title="icy planes and hills" class="miniimg2"/>
    <img src="http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/_Zuzii37VUO4/Ta0nTs8AbPI/AAAAAAAAFoU/zCvNKv4kfe4/s000/BeachWaves-By-RePublicDomain.jpg" title="sun rise with clouds" class="miniimg3"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="minicontainer">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-EyJOI3UFWvo/Te5KHGgOpSI/AAAAAAAAESY/PhG66jWB1OA/s200/blogger-featured-slideshow.png" title="Blogger Logo" class="miniimg"/>
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-BKPnpE6QpfY/TewL7Q16ipI/AAAAAAAAERg/pxn6NY1nNsg/s640/best-blogger-template-stunning-slider-magazine.PNG" title="blogger template" class="miniimg2"/>
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gxaZr19LXtY/TdRcJrxv3gI/AAAAAAAAD68/KaX9UN0B2nE/s640/advanced-design-magazine-blogger-template.PNG" title="another blogger template" class="miniimg3"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I just offer you a +1, for asking a coherent question, including (and properly formatting!) code ***and*** linking to a functional example..! Ah...such a nice change =)

Comment: thankyou :) i'm really glad i discovered Stackoverflow with a community that helps each other!

Comment: BTW ive updated it check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/Plugins4/T3J3r/49/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you change

```
$(".currentimgtitle").text(textval);
```

to

```
$(this).closest(".imgcontainer").find(".currentimgtitle").text(textval);
```

like you did a few lines higher ?

Comment: sorry, small error. Use `    $(this).closest(".imgcontainer").find(".currentimgtitle").text(textval);` instead

Comment: By the time I figured this out I saw that you're answer was exactly correct.  +1

Comment: yuupp that did it i figured it thankyou very much though i'll accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

While I see you've already accepted an answer, this approach seems to work pretty well:

```
$('.minicontainer img').click(
    function(){
        var miniImgSrc = this.src,
            imgTitle = this.title,
            $container = $(this).closest('.imgcontainer');
        $container
            .find('.presentimg')
            .attr('src',miniImgSrc);
        $container
            .find('.currentimgtitle')
            .attr('title',imgTitle)
            .text(imgTitle);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/T3J3r/38/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`element.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.title).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/T3J3r/36/

try this example, a bit cleaner. For the next step i`ve better wrap it in  for no js users.